# Office Ribbon Control SizeString

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to create a custom ribbon for ms access, and everything works fine, but when i try to increase the combo box with the SizeString attribute, the ribbon does not display at all, any help please.

```
      <comboBox id="cmbClient" label="Clients List" screentip="Select Client" supertip=" " onChange="OnChangeCombobox" getVisible="GetVisible" getEnabled="GetEnabled" 
            getItemCount="PIGetItemCount"
            getItemLabel="PIGetItemLabel"
            getItemID="PIGetItemID" 
            SizeString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            tag="RibbonName:=YCClientForm;inMenu:=;CustomTagValue1:=Client;CustomTagValue2:=;CustomTagValue3:=;DefaultValue:=;CustomPicture:=;CustomPicturePath:=">
      </comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xml attributes are case sensitive; use sizeString